# Image beyond bounds of container and clipping mask

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have html like this:

```
<div class='image-container'>
    <img src='path/to/image.png' />
</div>
```

I'm looking to accomplish two things:

1. Currently, I have jQuery that populates the `<img>` src, using the default file-upload dialogue.  However, no matter the size of the image, I'd like it to display in it's full width / height (over the bounds of its container) and have the container set to `overflow: hidden`.
2. Using jQueryUI, make the image draggable within the container, and continue to be clipped / masked by it's container

However, I can't figure out how to make the `<img>` retain it's full width / height, and not be scaled down by it's container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the height/width on the containing div, then the `img` element will retain it's own dimensions. Try this:

```
.image-container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

```js
$('.image-container img').draggable();
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ccqt00fq/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the image from going past the perimeters (avoiding white space) which is typical for zooming features, you can do this ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrs_snow/qryouxdw/)):

```
$('.image-container img').draggable({
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.position.top > 0) {
            ui.position.top = 0;
        }
        var topMax = ui.helper.parent().height() - ui.helper.height();
        if (ui.position.top < topMax) {
            ui.position.top = topMax;
        }
        if (ui.position.left > 0) {
            ui.position.left = 0;
        }
        var leftMax = ui.helper.parent().width() - ui.helper.width();
        if (ui.position.left < leftMax) {
            ui.position.left = leftMax;
        }
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.image-container {
    display: block;
    width: 380px;
    height: 380px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
```